# How do I compute Euler phi function efficiently for repeated prime factors?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

In RSA decryption problems, you have to compute $\phi(n)$ and then sometimes $\phi(\phi(n))$ quickly. For example, I had to compute $\phi(2^5)$ for one particular problem and it seems to me (for example in testing situations) that there has to be some kind of algorithm to calculate this since you can't just use the property that $\phi(x) = x-1$ for x prime.

Comment: Do you have the prime factorization? And are you an attacker, or do you have the necessary key?

Comment: I am the attacker

Comment: (e,n) = (17, 323) and the ciphertext was 185 but I was trying to keep the question general so that I could learn the underlying way to quickly compute $\phi(n)$ in a variety of problems

Comment: For the product $pq$ of two large primes, finding $\varphi(pq)$ is "just as difficult" as factorization. If we know $\varphi(pq)$, we can easily compute $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Euler%27s_totient_function&oldid=604162200#Euler.27s_product_formula), given any prime number $p$, $\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1} \cdot (p - 1)$, and given two coprime numbers $m$ and $n$, $\phi(m \cdot n) = \phi(m) \cdot \phi(n)$.

So, write the number's prime factorization as ${p_1}^{k_1} \cdot {p_2}^{k_2} \cdot \cdots$, and its totient is ${p_1}^{k_1 - 1} (p_1 - 1) \cdot {p_2}^{k_2 - 1} (p_2 - 1) \cdot \cdots$.

Comment: Note that computing the phi function may be prohibitively difficult if you don't know the number's prime factorization. If $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers, and we know what $pq$ and $\phi(pq)$ are, we can find what $p$ and $q$ are.

Comment: Wow $\phi(2^k) = p^(k-1)*(p-1)$ is exactly what I was looking for, what an amazing equality.

Answer (score 0):

Find all prime factors of $n$, then compute

$$\phi(n) = n\prod_{p|n}(1-\frac{1}{p})$$

where the product is over $n$'s prime factors.

Comment: … over $n$'s prime factors.

Comment: @WolfgangKais: Yup. Thanks for pointing that out.